# CSS3 image scale transition issue in IE11

Tags: css, css-transitions, internet-explorer-11

This code works fine in Chrome/Firefox/Safari/Opera on Mac OS X (http://jsfiddle.net/hfmhecmw/3/):

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="image" src="http://s29.postimg.org/fu0492g7r/lotus_flowers_wallpaper_hd_25.jpg"/>
</div>
```

---

```
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 320px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
    width: 320px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
    transition: transform 0.4s;
}

.container:hover .image {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.15);
    transform: scale(1.15);
}
```

But there is an issue: Windows 8.1/IE11 while image's scaling, it are: blurred, moved left on 1px and have something like 1px border around.

[image: Picture in normal state]
[image: Picture in transition state]

Are there any ways to make this animation smooth like in Chrome? Or it's normal for IE 11?

Comment: Not seeing the issue in IE11 on W7 64 bit. Frankly, if it's an issue that only applies for 0.4s it might be a niggle but it's not a deal breaker.

Comment: @Paulie_D I just want to know, it's a problem in my CSS, or browser bug, or normal render for IE 11.

Comment: What happens if you set the transition-duration to something much longer, like 3s?

Comment: @BjornJohnson I tried, the same effect.

Comment: Does it do the same if the scale is like 1.2 or 1.5?  (I can see the fiddle, but I am not on that OS and browser.)

Comment: @BjornJohnson yes(. P.S. You could use [Virtual Machines with IE](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) for free.